# S3 bucket name with dots returns "must be addressed using the specified endpoint"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, npm

I've been using node [s3-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-cli) library for a while to upload files into my S3 buckets. This worked for example:

```
s3-cli sync --delete-removed dist s3://domain-admin-dev
```

But when I run this

```
s3-cli sync --delete-removed dist s3://sudomain.domain.com
```

it returns this error:

> Error: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

What should I do?

*Note:* I found some posts on the web talking about the S3 bucket not belonging to the right region, however the s3://sudomain.domain.com belongs to the same region as the s3://domain-admin-dev one. So it doesn't make sense for that to be the problem.

Comment: When I ran into this, the raw error response did contain the endpoint I needed. (If `s3-cli` doesn't show it to you, you may be able to see it by pointing your browser at the "wrong" location if subdomain.domain.com is a CNAME for some generic S3 domain, or by using another client.) Some S3/AWS clients accept an option like `--endpoint` to force requests to a certain endpoint.

Comment: *"it doesn't make sense for that to be the problem"*  Actually, it makes perfect sense.  `https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` is always routed by DNS to the correct region for that bucket.  S3 provisions this automatically.  `https://bucket.with.dots.s3.amazonaws.com` doesn't work because of how wildcard SSL certificates work, so if this utility reverts to the alternate form, `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket.with.dots/` you will go to the wrong region unless the bucket is in `us-east-1`.  Buckets with dots have to be addressed as `https://s3.{aws-region}.amazonaws.com/bucket.with.dots/`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot your suggestion didn't work.. see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this whole approach was wrong. I simply had to add a cloud front distribution (ie a CDN) and then link it's origin to the s3 bucket (the name of which I changed back from `s3://sudomain.domain.com` to `s3://domain-admin-dev`, thus making my cli command work just fine). I then created a CNAME record in my godaddy pointing the subdomain to the cloud front Origin.

The process is depicted here:

[image]

note: since cloud front is a cdn, the cache must be [invalidated](https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&q=https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html&source=gmail&ust=1523343734914000&usg=AFQjCNFw3cUfvot-Xx_EHBMawP2NRvTuxw) everytime it's updated.